# How to call MVC controller from angularJS ?Can we do that?

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am working on a application where it was developed by angularJs,MVC,Asp.net,angular....I am adding a new feature on angular JS when we click on button from this page it should go to MVC controller.I have done this using  ng-href but unable to pass parameters .

my code something like
ng-href="/controller/action"

Expected:

ng-href="/controller/action/param=paramvalues

Any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: Query parameters are prefixed with `?` not `/` i.e. `<a ng-href="/controller/action?parameter=paramvalue">Click here</a>`